# Plotting time series from a pandas dataframe: split according to date

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I'm trying to compare yearly expenditures (september to september) using pandas and matplotlib.

Currently, i'm basically using this approach (but it only works with the calendar year):

```
pivoted = data.pivot_table(index=data.index.dayofyear, columns=data.index.year, values='expenditure')
pivoted = pivoted.fillna(0)
for year in pivoted:
    plt.plot(pivoted[year].cumsum(), label=f"Year {year}")
plt.show()
```

It's nice, and I get this kind of result (I removed some presentation code in the above snippet):

[image: Comparison of yearly expenditure, using a cumulative sum]

What I'm now trying to do is to have the same kind of plot, but starting from september of one year, and ending in the september of the following year.

I wonder what would be the best approach: I tried splitting the data, using for example `data['2017-09-01':'2018-09-01'], and then plotting it, but I lack a way to "forget" about the year (and only care about the day).

Any hint on how to do this?

Comment: You want to show a datum that denotes a later point in time to be shown earlier on the axis? I have the feeling that one shouldn't do that. Rather one would plot the data from september 2017 (start of axis) to september 2018 (end of axis).

Comment: Yeah, what you describe is what I want to do: having september at the start of the axis, and september at the end of the axis